# Denying main links with .htaccess or anything else

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using an encrypted php program with smarty template.

I wanted to open links such as `index.php?page=login` to open with login.php, so I used Rewrite mode in `.htaccesss`, for example

```
RewriteRule ^/*login.php$ /index.php?page=login [L]
```

in a few pages there should be a query for errors such as

```
RewriteRule ^/*support.php?(.+)$ /index.php?page=support&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It works but I need to deny the main URLs so when users enters index.php?a=login manually nothing (or the main page) would show up and he should open the link only with /login.php.
Is there a way to do this?

A little help please...

Answer (score 0):

It should work with a coirresponding rewirterule before(!) the other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/*index.php?a=login$ / [L]
```